# NextJS Environment Variables vs Constants File

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, next.js13

I don't know whether to use a Constants.js file or an Environment Variable file in NextJS.

I have read that env.production is kept on the NextJS 'server-side' so it can't be accessed by hackers when they download the front-end code. Is it the same for a constant file? Obviously, I don't want users to be able to look at my front-end code and discover my 'TOP_SECRET_API_KEY'.

```
constants.js :

  export const WEBSITE_NAME = 'MyWebsite.com';
  export const WEBSITE_URL = 'https://www.mywebsite.com';
  export const TOP_SECRET_API_KEY = '1234abcd';


Use the constants file in components:

  import { TOP_SECRET_API_KEY } from './constants';

  const secretKey = TOP_SECRET_API_KEY;
```

And the alternative...

```
  env.production:

    WEBSITE_NAME = MyWebsite.com
    WEBSITE_URL = https://www.mywebsite.com
    TOP_SECRET_API_KEY = 1234abcd


  Use the env variables in components:

    process.env.TOP_SECRET_API_KEY
```

What is the standard practice? Constants file or Env file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are variables that change based on the environment: Development, production, test. If you set the env file, you access them via `process.env` and this will signal the other developers there are some environment variables and those should be set properly on each environment.

If you set the variables in a constant file, that means these variables do not change, they are the same in each environment. However, if you have sensitive information on these files, you should not push it to the public repos. In one specific case, if I work with Ethereum contracts project, I set the account private keys in the constant file because I need them only once when I deploy the contract and then delete the values.

Answer (score 1):

To store sensitive information such as API keys, passwords, and tokens, use environment variables. These variables can be accessed by the client-side code without exposing the values publicly. Constant files are useful for frequently used values, but it is advisable to avoid storing sensitive information in them to prevent the exposure of such information to the public.